# MVVM Light toolkit - maintained? Here today - gone tomorrow? 

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have been taking a look at mvvm light toolkit, i must admit i haven't got a lot of experience with it but i live what i see..

I did use the mvvm toolkit (microsoft) but currently use vs 2010 and no templates are available as yet.

I was looking for some insight into mvvm light toolkit...

Is it always maintained ?  i..e its not going to be gone tomorrow...

Or shoudl i be looking elsewhere??

I would really appreciate any feedback...

I also saw some info on how it is blendable which the mvvm toolkit (microsoft) didn't seem to have..

Prism also seems to be also a likely candidate but from what i understand its not a MVVM framework / toolkit

i would be using it with wpf

Any help really appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I will from now on use SO more actively to support the MVVM Light Toolkit (and outsource the support to others too ;)

I am committed to support and update the MVVM Light Toolkit as long as it makes sense, and as long as I have capacity to do so. Right now I am exactly in the middle of writing my new book about Silverlight 4, so obviously my capacity is reduced, but I still create new updates and new blog posts regularly. I am aware that, as for most open source frameworks, the documentation should be better, and I plan to work on that as soon as I can.

If I should find myself unable to work on the toolkit anymore, I will make sure to advertise this fact and do my best to find a new maintainer.

Thanks for the concern :)
Laurent

Comment: Thanks, this was the kind of answer i was looking for... i didn't want to commit to a new framework without some confirmation....  I really do like what i see.... I am sold .. thanks again!

Comment: @LBugnion, could you please shed light on the future of MVVM Light for desktop WPF applications?
It seems you're focused on Silverlight, Windows Phone, Windows 8 directions and ordinary desktop WPF (not Win8) direction looks abandoned. I hardly could find some examples for WPF desktop apps, so had to gather knowledges based on existed Silverlight/WP stuff.

Comment: Hi, the WPF version is almost the same code than the others, so any change I make automatically applies to the WPF version as well. We actively use the WPF version in quite a few projects, so it is definitely going to be maintained for a long time. I am thinking of adding async-specific features which would apply to the WPF 4.5 version. I plan to continue maintaining the WPF3.5 and WPF4 versions as well because they are widely used. HTH, Laurent

Comment: @LBugnion Can I ask you how you made the MSI installer for MVVMLight? Did you use WiX Installer? Just wondering..

Answer (score 7):

Laurent is a fellow Microsoft MVP and I know he uses the toolkit regularly so I would expect regular updates for the time being.

Also, it is a codeplex project so you can get the code at anytime and fix / change anything you need to, even if it is not maintained in the future.

http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/

Just FYI it looks like Mar 17th was the last check in on codeplex so it is still actively being worked on.

Answer (score 3):

The MVVM Light Toolkit has been updated quite regularly up to now. Since the maintainer, Laurent Bugnion, uses the framework himself, I think it will also be updated in the future. However, you can never know that for sure.

The Prism/CAL framework can also be used with MVVM. Actually, that's what I am currently doing. You can also combine parts of the MVVM Light toolkit and Prism/CAL.

There are also several other MVVM frameworks out there. If you are interested in them, you should have a look at [this overview](http://www.japf.fr/2009/11/discover-compare-existing-mvvm-frameworks/) by Jeremy Alles.

Answer (score 0):

MVVM Light is now available for Visual Studio 2010.